# How to download all the files from a folder in Firebase Storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I want to download all the files from my Firebase project's folder.

I've tried the following things:

Using NPM:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase login
firebase storage:download gs://tridosha-iks-research-project.appspot.com/audio .
```

Error: storage:download is not a Firebase command
(I've tried storage:get too)

Using gsutil:

```
gsutil -r cp gs://tridosha-iks-research-project.appspot.com/audio .
```

```
Error: cp unknown host
gs://tridosha-iks-research-project.appspot.com/audio isn't a valid hostname
```

Using Python:

```
import os
from firebase_admin import credentials, storage, initialize_app

# Replace these with your actual Firebase configuration values
firebase_config = {
    "project_number": "project number",
    "project_id": "id",
    "storage_bucket": "bucket"
  },

# Initialize Firebase
cred = credentials.Certificate("/home/shreyansh/Desktop/IKS/google-services.json")  # Replace with your service account key file
initialize_app(cred, firebase_config)

# Reference to your Firebase Storage bucket
bucket = storage.bucket()

# List the files in a specified folder
folder_path = "audio/"
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder_path)

# Download the files to a local directory
local_directory = "/home/shreyansh/PAISA/IKS/audio"  # Replace with your local directory

for blob in blobs:
    local_file_path = os.path.join(local_directory, blob.name)
    blob.download_to_filename(local_file_path)
    print(f"Downloaded {blob.name} to {local_file_path}")
```

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shreyansh/Desktop/PAISA/IKS/download.py", line 12, in <module>
    cred = credentials.Certificate("/home/shreyansh/Desktop/PAISA/IKS/google-services.json")  # Replace with your service account key file
  File "/home/shreyansh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 93, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Invalid service account certificate. Certificate must contain a '
ValueError: Invalid service account certificate. Certificate must contain a "type" field set to "service_account"
```

.

How do I download all the files in my folder?
it's okay if I can download the entire bucket too...

Comment: It's supposed to be `gsutil cp -r`, isn't it?  You're showing the arguments in a different order.  I suggest reviewing the examples in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#copying-tofrom-subdirectories;-distributing-transfers-across-machines).

Comment: @DougStevenson using gsutil cp -r gives me the error "No command was given.
Choose one of -b, -d, -e, or -r to do something."

Comment: Does anything in the documentation work?  Are you able to copy anything at all using one of their examples as a basis? I've never had a problem with gsutil.